# Help me with the expression "You can't announce him a cheater because it's speculation"

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say something like "You can't announce him a cheater because it's speculation." I know that *announce* is the wrong word, so I need something to replace it. I thought of *proclaim*, but I don't think it sounds right, either. Help?

Comment: *Proclaim* is fine, but you might just say *call*. The second part of the sentence, though, also needs work.  Do you mean that you can't call him a cheater because it's just speculation at this point?

Comment: @Jim yes that is correct

Comment: @noob: then drop "the". A newly introduced topic is indefinite in English unless it is explicitly identified, so _because of the speculation that ..._ is OK, but otherwise it's _because of speculation_.

Comment: @ColinFine point noted

Comment: @Jim: I think even *denounce* is a little stiff/dated, but *proclaim* sounds positively antediluvian to me in this context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- It's funny how words strike different people- *Denounce* sounds more stiff/dated to me than *proclaim*.  I think the most *current* word here is simply *call* or maybe *label*.

Comment: @Jim: I suppose when you've got a couple of near-synonyms like that, neither of which are particularly common ([englishclub](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/common-words-5000.htm) puts *proclaim* at #4517, and *denounce* doesn't make it into their *5000 most common words* list at all) there's much more scope for a US/UK split on exactly how we feel about the words. But that's a good point about *call/label* being common/current alternatives. OP's *announce* suggests he had *denounce* at the back of his mind, but if you don't want to post *call/label*, I'll acknowledge them in mine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- nice link.  I'm not gonna post so they're all yours.

Comment: @Jim: I was quite pleased with that link myself when I found it just now (I added it to "ELU Favourites" in my browser straight away!). I'd tried half-a-dozen other likely candidates already, and was just about to abandon all hope. I haven't explored the rest of the site yet, but that list certainly gave a promising first impression.

Answer (score 6):

The phrasing you're looking for is...

> “You can't [denounce](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denounce) him **as** a cheater...” *(to pronounce especially publicly to be blameworthy or evil)*

Note that you need to include *"as"* in such constructions. In principle you could just use *pronounce* (which doesn't need *"as"*), but that's far less common, and sounds a bit dated/formal/stilted to me.

Also note that *cheater* wouldn't normally be used by competent speakers in this way (it *is* on the increase among younger people, but it's still mainly a marker for "non-native speaker"). Given that *denounce* is a relatively "up-market" word, you'd be more likely to see it used with, say, *fraudster, swindler, trickster*, etc. Or just plain *cheat* (in short, anything but *cheater!*)

---

As pointed out by @Jim in comments to the question, in popular parlance today you'd probably be much more likely to hear *call* or *label*, rather than *denounce*. And as pointed out by @Peter below, *cheater* is far more common in US than in UK usage (and it's a [regularly-inflected form](http://grammar.about.com/od/il/g/inflecterm.htm)), so my carping about it should be taken with a substantial pinch of salt!

Comment: One might say: "You can't denounce him as a **cheat** …".

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but there is one more thing I need, what if context is not specifically negative, I used it just an example. What should be the preferred phrase in that case?

Comment: @noob: I'm not sure what you mean by *not specifically negative*. In practice, I suspect people don't often have real-world situations where they might want to convey something like *"You can't publicly endorse him as a good person just because of one isolated good thing about him"*, but I suppose *endorse* is probably as good a word as any for that context. And as for "neutral" ways of putting it - why would anyone ever need to say anything at all if they don't have either a positive or a negative attitude to the label being cautioned against? Maybe *Don't pigeonhole him*? I don't know.

Comment: I believe the word "cheater" is fine in American English (Ngrams says that it's twice as common here as in British English).

Comment: @Peter: Ah. That would explain why I hear it more among younger speakers these days (they're exposed to far more examples of American usage than I ever was in my youth). It sounds a bit strange/uneducated to my ear, but I guess that's just because I'm on the cusp of transitioning into a grumpy old man. Whereas I should be championing the usage, since it's a perfectly natural "regularisation". I don't think the Welsh actually say *Jones the bake* for *baker* (if they did, I'd doubtless find fault) - but morphologically, *Jones the cheat* is no different. I'm unmasked as a linguistic luddite!

Comment: Not only is *cheater* a perfectly good word, none of your suggested replacements work: unless specified otherwise, a *cheater* is an adulterer, i.e. a man who cheats on his wife (or vice versa).

Comment: @Marthaª: I hadn't realised that. So does that mean in *your* usage there are two words - *cheater = adulterer*, and *cheat = any other kind of dishonest person*?

Comment: @Marthaª The meaning of 'cheater' seems pretty contextual to me - if I was watching a monopoly game and one player called another a cheater, I wouldn't immediately assume adultery. Maybe the assumption of the 'adulterer' meaning is a regional thing?

Comment: @user867, context can certainly "specify otherwise", i.e. no, if we're playing poker and someone calls me a cheater, I wouldn't start protesting that I'm not married.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, *cheater* can be used for other types of dishonesty, it's just that absent other cues, my default interpretation of the OP's example sentence is adultery. I wouldn't be particularly likely to use the word *cheat* as a noun.

Comment: @user867,Martha: Fascinating. I see [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define+cheater&oq=define+cheater&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.658&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=u&q=cheater&tbs=dfn:1&sa=X&ei=TIfGUKOhELKa0QXt-IDICw&ved=0CC4QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=75e263ab38675344&bpcl=39650382&biw=1356&bih=856) tells me a *cheater* is also *a pair of glasses or sunglasses*. Where on earth did *that* come from?

Comment: *Cheater* = glasses is somewhat antiquated at this point; I think it stems from glasses allowing the user to see things he wouldn't see otherwise. It's just a short (albeit hyperbolic) step from *leveling the playing field* to *giving four-eyes an advantage*.